# How can I get Wordpress user ID?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to use the Twitter follow button for site authors on all posts.

The Twitter structure is here:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @twitterapi</a>
```

Yes, it works but this place must be generic. I should import Wordpress `$user->ID` in this structure. How can I do this?

Comment: The wordpress user id or the twitter user id?

Comment: It's Wordpress user ID.

Comment: The explanations you're providing in the Answer bellow **should be [edit]ed into the Question**. Also, you don't mention *how and where are you inserting the code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_current_user_id()` in wordpress.

To get the author of the current post try the following

```
  <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php esc_attr_e(get_the_author()) ?>" 
     class="twitter-follow-button" 
     data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @<?php echo get_the_author() ?></a>
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I import this function in Twitter HTML structure?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question then, can you clarify the steps the user would take and the desired outcome.

Comment: The site have 2 authors. When I click anything post, get Twitter follow box about that user. So, twitter.com/twitter api not valid for me. It's must be twitter.com/WordpressUserID

Comment: Wouldn't you want to follow the author of the post the button is on?

Comment: I want to convert this structure to dynamic: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button

Comment: @MaryJane check it out my answer I think could help you

Comment: @MaryJane see my edit, i think its what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the current user logged you can simple user this wordpress function:

```
get_current_user_id()
```

To put it in whatever html code you should just open the tags  where you need a dynamic value.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow <?php get_current_user_id() ?></a>
```

or using shortcut tags:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow <?=get_current_user_id()?></a>
```